# Setting up a cascode amplifier in a schematic

Tags: mosfet, cascode

I had been thinking this for hours. If anyone here could point me if I'm doing the schematic correcly I'd appreciate it.

Here's the problem:

Consider a cascode amplifier consisting of two stacked NMOS transistors M1 and M2 (this is the driving stage) feeding into a single PMOS current source load M3. Vout is taken from the drain that is common to M2 and M3. The design specifications are: a) AV ≥ 100, b) each of the transistors must be in saturation mode. Use only the ADS optimizer in this design, and work with Harmonic Balance simulation.

This is my schematic, you can simply focus on the circuit itself, not in all the other things:
[image]

I'd love to get some feedback in how to improve my design. Thanks.

Comment: To improve the design a statement of what the design is intended to achieve is necessary. Input impedance, output impedance, frequency of operation (range), quiescent current, power supply range, input and output maximum amplitudes before distorting, what the signal source is, what the output load can be. There are probably other things to consider too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply a certain (DC) voltage as Vgs, like you do for M1 and M3 then these transistors will try to make "a" current flow. The value of that current is anyone's guess. You should first **bias** all transistors properly, make sure their Vgs and Vds are OK at DC.

My guess is that the drain of M3 will be either very close to 5 V or very close to 1 V. That means that either M3 or both M1 and M2 are in triode mode (so not in saturation). That will mean you will have **very little voltage gain**.

Like this your circuit aims to be a current source against current source (M1 + M2 vs M3) and only one source can "win".

I suggest looking more into amplifier topologies because explaining what you need to do to make this a "proper" amplifier requires almost a full design course.

Comment: You need to sense the operating point (Vout) and adjust the gate voltage of the PMOS (with a slow filter, and negative feedback) to regulate the long-term Vout to be where acceptable linear (both M2 and M3 in SAT, also) is achieved.

Comment: What @analogsystemsrf means is a DC-feedback loop. That's semi-advanced analog design. OP is till biasing his MOSFETs using a DC voltage source (instead of current source and MOSFET diode) so he's not ready for that yet.